How to put a space between a lower case, period, [SPACE], and capital letter with MARIADB query
I have been trying for over a week to replace thousands of grammar errors in a data feed file of 103,927 products.
I'm stuck on how to put a space between a lower case letter or number, period, [NEED SPACE HERE], and capital letter.
My (bad) code only replaces the first instance in the product description but I need it to replace every instance in every record.
I can't simply replace every period with period space because the descriptions have decimal values and http addresses.
I have some experience with MYSQL programming but I am a novice on regular expression (I just don't get them).
I have tried the following code...tested and verified REGEXP string at regex101 and notepad++:
SELECT REPLACE(`desc`, REGEXP_SUBSTR(`desc`, '[A-Za-z0-9]\\.[A-Z]'), REGEXP_SUBSTR(`desc`, '[A-Za-z0-9]\\.\\s[A-Z]')) FROM `build_datafeed` WHERE `desc` IS NOT NULL

It only modifies the first instance of a period without a space after it. I.E. use.This is changed to ushis
Flustered but not defeated, I tried a different approach:
SELECT REPLACE(`desc`, REGEXP_SUBSTR(`desc`, '[A-Za-z0-9]\\.[A-Z]'), CONCAT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(`desc`, '[A-Za-z0-9]\\.'), REGEXP_SUBSTR(`desc`, '\\s[A-Z]'))) FROM `build_datafeed` WHERE `desc` IS NOT NULL


Same as the last...only the first instance got modified. I.E. use.This became use. uhis...some progress but not quite what I need.
I have tried various combinations of REPLACE, SUBSTR, REGEXP_REPLACE, and REGEXP_SUBSTR. I even attempted using PHP but that really slowed things down.
Any ideas? Thanks.
Environment:
Server Host: localhost (127.0.0.1)
Server OS: Windows NT DESKTOP-4B8U62U 10.0 build 19045 (Windows 10) AMD64
Server Date: 06/07/2024 11:39:28  
Server Up Time: Unsupported
HTTP Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.0.23
PHP Version: 8.0.23 (Zend: 4.0.23)
PHP File Uploads: On
Upload Max Size: 512M
PHP Memory Limit: -1
POST Max Size: 1024M
Database Engine: MySQL 10.4.25-MariaDB
Database Host: localhost (127.0.0.1)
Database Date: 06/07/2024 11:39:28
Database Data Size: 361,500 kB
Database Index Size: 50,015 kB
MySQL Slow Query Log Status: Off
MySQL Mode: NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION


So - as an example, you want to change a string like "a.B c.D 3.F" to "a. B c. D 3. F"?

@Mike Did you try this demo? SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(\desc`, '\b\.(?=\p{Lu})', '. ');At least the MariaDB fiddle seems to work, doesn't it. What's unclear is that you wrote "...put a space between a **lower case** letter or number, period..." but in your code you use[A-Za-z0-9]\.` which also contains upper case letters before the period (same for the demo).

@bobblebubble Yes, I was not as clear on the description as I should have been. Both upper and lower case and numbers before the period and only upper case after the period. I'd like numbers after the period too but I'm really not sure how to approach that...LOL. I'll give your code a try shortly. Thanks.

@bobblebubble, I see my answer is effectively the same as what you propose, the only difference being that I included the period in the lookbehind so that only a space is inserted.

Please answer @DanielWaechter's question. (I presume the answer is "yes".) Doing so earlier would have clarified what you are trying to do. You could also clarify your question by replacing, "I'm stuck on .... capital letter" with something more precise, such as "I wish to insert a space before every uppercase letter that is preceded by a period that in turn is preceded by a lowercase letter or a digit" (assuming that in fact is what you wish to do).

Please do not edit your question after others have already answered.  Stack Overflow is not a blog site.

@DanielWaechter and Cary Swoveland - Make this read correctly: https://asdfasdf.com.Nope, I give this a 0.NOT.53.44X33.22.This    -   Whoever bobblebuble is, your suggestion works for the way I described it. I would also like it to include whole and decimal numbers after the period as well. bobblebubble's post at the end of this thread disappeared so I can't mark it as the accepted answer.

@Tim Biegeleisen Excuse me? I was not aware there were rules against editing the original post with updates. Why did Stack put an edit link there?

@Tim, surely it's acceptable--even advised--to edit one's question to make it more clear, provided the essence of the question is not alerted. Have any of the edits effectively changed the question?

Mike, if you mean a space is to be inserted before an uppercase letter or the first letter of a sequence of digits that represent a non-negative integer or float, provided the said character is preceded by a period preceded by a lowercase letter or digit (whew), you can replace matches of [a-z0-9]\.\K(?=[A-Z]|(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?\b) with a space. ? makes (?:\.\d+) optional. Note 023 and 012.34 are not valid Demo. If that's not exactly what you want you may be able to modify the regex accordingly. ("altered" in my previous comment.)

@CarySwoveland When I first tried this with [A-Z] at dbfiddle, I noticed the collation-concern, that @TimBiegeleisen at least mentions and targets with (?-i) in his pattern. I found out, that - at least in the fiddle - \p{Ll} or [[:upper:]] would (surprisingly) work accordingly. This is weird behavior, isn't it. For the replacement string, I don't understand that, where captures were used, why nobody used \\1 instead of $1 which is not supposed to work with mariadb? An interesting question with obscurities from all sides (question, answers, mariadb).

@Mike I haven't posted an answer yet because I'm still unclear about the exact requirements.  However, I have learned something new from your question. Finally... you have so many options, you would be able to adjust any solution appropriately (and maybe even add your own answer).

@bobblebubble, yes, weird. I can shed no light.

We can use REGEXP_REPLACE() as follows:
REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello.World', '([a-z0-9])\\.([A-Z])', '$1. $2');
-- Hello. World

The regex pattern here will match:

([a-z0-9]) a single lowercase letter or number (and capture in $1)
\. literal dot
([A-Z]) an uppercase letter (and capture in $2)

We then replace with $1. $2 to introduce a space after the period.
Demo
Note: The REGEXP_REPLACE() function follows the case sensitivity of the underlying collation of the table/database.  For case insensitive collations, the above answer would also target substrings such as hello.world.  For case sensitive and binary collations, the answer as given above would work.
If you are using a case insensitive collation, you may still force a case sensitive regex search by using the (?-i) flag:
REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello.World', '(?-i)([a-z0-9])\\.([A-Z])', '$1. $2');


Worked good as a SELECT (with A-Z added to your code for the left side of the period). But weird things happened when I converted it to an UPDATE. 1. 2 replaced every period. UPDATE build_datafeed SET desc = REGEXP_REPLACE(desc, '(?-i)([A-Za-z0-9])\.([A-Z])', '\1. \2') WHERE desc RLIKE '(?-i)([A-Za-z0-9])\.([A-Z])' AND desc IS NOT NULL

I understand MariaDB supports the PCRE regex engine. One therefore may replace zero-width matches of the following regular expression with a space.
(?<=[a-z0-9]\.)(?=[A-Z])

Demo

(?<=[a-z0-9]\.) is a positive lookbehind ((?<=...)) that asserts the match must be preceded by a period that is in turn preceded by character in the character class, namely, a lowercase letter or digit.
(?=[A-Z]) is a positive lookahead ((?=...)) that asserts the match must be followed by a character in the character class, namely, an uppercase letter.
If, for example, the string were "a.A", the expression would match the zero-width string between "a." and "A", with "a. A" being returned after the space is inserted.

It may be necessary to write \\. rather than \., but regex101 does not permit that when testing regular expressions with the PCRE engine.

Alternatively, one may replace the positive lookbehind with
[a-z0-9]\.\K

so that the expression becomes
[a-z0-9]\.\K(?=[A-Z])

(again, perhaps the backslashes may need to be doubled). The token \K causes the start of the match to be reset to the current string location and for all previously-consumed characters to be discarded.
Demo

Not even close. Test this: http://asdfasdf.com.Nope, I give this a 0.NOT.53.44X33.22.This ain't working.

I corrected my answer. As should be evident, I had misunderstood your question. Saying so would have been preferable to being snarky and not even clever. Your link is broken, incidentally.

Not trying to be snarky...it is just an example. Stack's system removed the http:// from what I typed in and that is only a make believe link. I'll give your update another try. Thanks. @Cary Swoveland.

See my comment on your question directed to @bobblebubble.

@Mike I recommend reading How do I format my code blocks. It helped me very much in the beginning. If you want to present a link as string, just put it inside backticks. It will show up like: http://asdfasdf.com.nope/

If I understand what you want correctly, you want to use REGEXP_REPLACE with capture groups. The following will translate a string like "a.B c.D 3.F" to "a. B c. D 3. F".
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(`desc`, '([a-z0-9]\\.)([A-Z])', '$1 $2') FROM `build_datafeed` WHERE `desc` IS NOT NULL


FYI: In MariaDB maybe '\\1 \\2' is needed as the replacement string.

This puts a space before .com in http links.

This does what I asked in the original question:
UPDATE `build_datafeed` SET `desc` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`desc`, '\\\\b\\\\.(?=\\\\p{Lu})', '. ') WHERE `desc` IS NOT NULL

Don't ask why so many backslashes. I'm running this through PHP. Somehow this works, but doubles didn't.

Try that with "_.A".  ("_" is a word character). See word boundaries.

@Mike Always good to echo your $var that contains the statement. You will see, the string actually contains two backslashes (escape-character in PHP).
